# State machine - How to pass information on what to do on success to state

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, state-machine

I am using my own state machine for my AI in my city management game, it works fairly well. I uses a very simple interface:

```
public interface IState
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    void Enter();
    void Execute();
    void Exit();
}
```

To change state:

```
public void ChangeState(IState newState)
    {

        if (currentState != null)
            currentState.Exit();

        if (currentState != newState)
        {
            currentState = newState;
            currentState.Enter();
        }
    }
```

My only issue with it is that I find my self re-writing a lot of logic, to give a scenario:

There are bakers, blacksmiths, construction workers, and more. All these professions have a state that find the closest storage facility and go to it to gather the material they need for their job.

The same logic is used for all of them, apart from the line that says what to do when you get to the storage, i.e a baker will want to get wheat and then return to their bakery. A Blacksmith will want to get some iron and return to their blacksmith.

Basically what they do is:

1. Find storage
2. Go to storage
3. If storage has resource, change state to go back to workplace
4. Else find next closest storage and see if that storage has the resource
5. repeat 3 until found resource.

As you can imagine, I have the exact same issue with state "go back to workplace", where its basically the exact same logic in the state, except what to do on arrival.

Is there some smart way I can create a single state called "FindStorageState" and pass it information on what to do when my unit has arrived?

Here is a good example of what a profession can look like:

[image]

Comment: Why not just store that extra info in the class that implements the interface? Depending on how exactly you need that info it can be anything from a simple value to a `delegate` that gets executed at the right moment (or even another class with methods)

Comment: @UnholySheep Hmm well there is no "Baker" class, or "Blacksmith" class, they are all just workers with different professions, so to find a baker I do `find all workers where currentProfessions == "baker"`

Comment: I meant you can store it in your `FindStorageState` class

Comment: So you mean pass it the profession and depending on the profession it will react differently?

Comment: Do you even need to know the profession there? I would only store the storage and/or resource type, since that seems to be the only info you need

Comment: @UnholySheep True that might work, although might lead to a lot of if-checks to decide what item to display, what animation to play, where to go after, which state to change to, and so on.

Comment: Same behavior template but different details sounds like the Template Method. One of your states should implement it, the Execute possibly.

Comment: @WiktorZychla do you mean generic method?

Comment: Dont bother about the downvote, just how it is, look the front page, everything gets downvoted for no reason... as for your issue, i think you should have a worker base class with all the methods (find shop, action at shop, action at home,...), all virtual, so you can have subtypes inheriting. Those are blacksmith and so on. Each of those implements as needed. The overall system only deals with worker type.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I did, All the top results were Generic methods in C#.

Comment: @Majs How are you setting each AI agent's "worker type"?  Do you have a `MonoBehaviour` component attached to each game object that has a `WorkerType` enum that is set to `Baker`, `Blacksmith`, etc?  Or are you doing something different?